# ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for services: 'sqlite3'

Tags: sqlite, docker, docker-compose

```
webapp:
  build: ./webapp
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
   - .:/code

services:
  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/Users/vijayraghunath/Desktop/assignment/webapp
```

Above is my docker-compose.yml file. When I try to launch the Python Flask web application by the command,

```
docker-compose up --build
```

it gives the error as in the title. I am using the sqlite db.

Answer (score 1):

You've merged the version 1 (deprecated) syntax when you don't include a version line, with the version 2 syntax that moved services under a `services` top level. You need to pick one syntax or the other, you can't parse both simultaneously.

Here's the version 2 syntax:

```
version: '2'

services:
  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
     - ./db/:/Users/vijayraghunath/Desktop/assignment/webapp
  webapp:
    build: ./webapp
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
```

Note, be careful with spacing in the file since yaml is white space sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It worked and was able to proceed further.